# if dentro de transaccion en mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

quiero ejecutar una transaccion para mi programa y escribi el siguiente query, donde la tabla insumo representa ingredientes de una receta de cocina e insumosxreceta los insumos que cada receta necesita, la insumo.cantidad es la cantididad de ese insumo que se tiene e insumoxreceta.cantidad es la cantidad de insumo necesario para la preparacion

```
start transaction;
update insumo i
join insumoxreceta ix
on ix.id_insumo=i.id_insumo
set i.cantidad=i.cantidad-ix.cantidad
where ix.id_receta=1;
if i.cantidad<0 THEN
rollback;
else
commit;
end if;
```

pero por alguna razon workbench se esta quejando del codigo diciendo if not valid at this possition, quisiera saber donde esta mi falla para solucionarlo, gracias

Comment: Te da error porque no sabe que es i aqui `if i.cantidad<0 THEN
rollback;
else
commit;` Prueba algo asi `if (SELECT cantidad FROM insumo join insumoxreceta ix on ix.id_insumo=i.id_insumo WHERE ix.id_receta=1;)<0 THEN`

Comment: gracias, acabo de hacer esa correccion tal como me dijiste, pero me dice que el if no es valido en esa posicion y no se donde mas ponerlo

Comment: Perdón pensaba que era igual que Sql Server porque no pruebas quitando la transaccion y solo agregarle al Where `and (i.cantidad-ix.cantidad) > 0` asi solo actualiza si es mayor a 0 la cantidad

Comment: funciona muchas gracias

Comment: De nana. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

En MySQL, IF es mas practico en procedimientos almacenados o triggers, puedes crear facilmente un procedimiento y hacer el llamado

```
           DELIMITER $$
        DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedute_test
        CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_test(IN parametro VARCHAR(45))
        BEGIN
            IF (parametro>0) THEN
                INSERT INTO tabla(campo) VALUES (parametro);
            END IF;
        END $$
        DELIMITER ;
```

No obstante la manera correcta de usar IF sería:

```
UPDATE  tabla
SET     campo = IF(campoX = 'Valor',  campo - 1, campo)
WHERE   id = 1;
```